# bash: how get xsel -o to paste to focused window if command invoked by hotkey in fluxbox

Tags: linux, bash

The trackpad on my laptop will not middle-mouse paste.  I figured it should be easy to simulate, just focus the target app and invoke 'xsel -o' with a hotkey from fluxbox.  But it won't work, that is, xsel -o operates, but its output does not go to the focussed app.

Man xsel states that the -o option sends the current selection to standard output, which I assumed would be the app with focus.  Could someone explain why it does not do so in this situation, and how to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

That's not what "standard output" means.

Standard output is where commands like `echo` and `printf` send their output by default. It is the screen in a terminal. Run `xsel -o` in your terminal and you will see the output displayed.

You need a tool that actually simulates the middle click or simulates an X11 paste.

I believe you can use [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to do this sort of thing (among other tools).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with **xdotool**:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus click 2
```